# PHP MySql - SELECT where similar_text()>x

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables called reference and list. Both have two fields: id and name.

```
reference:
ref_id, ref_name
1, john
2, georges
etc...

list:
lst_id, lst_name
1, steward
2, james
3, john
4, jones
5, georges
etc...
```

I would like to select the name from both tables where similar_text()>60. Here below the output I would like to have:

```
ref_name, lst_name, similar_text()
john, john, 100
john, jones, 67
georges, georges, 100
```

Note that steward and james should be left out as the similar_text() is below 60.

Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your relies. Cheers. Marc. Oh, by the way, I am open to better solutions to achieve my goal...

Comment: Please clarify how do you define "similar_text()". For example john and jones gives 67. How is this 67 calculated?

Comment: What is that similar_text() function? Is there such one in MySQL?

Comment: Oh yeah. similar_text() is a php function that retrieves a match between two strings expressed in percentage: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.similar-text.php

Comment: You can not use PHP function in MySQL query though.

Comment: okay. Do you know though if something similar can be done with the LIKE in sql? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will most likely need [levenshtein in mysql](http://prglog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-implement-levenshtein-algotithm.html). This will allow you to calculate the differences in strings.

you could then do something like:

```
SELECT ref_name, lst_name, LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO( ref_name, lst_name ) as textDiff
FROM reference, list
HAVING textDiff > 60;
```

Or something similar.

**NOTE:** When working on large datasets this will most definitely have performance issues.

Comment: Give me a sec to test this out... Tks

Answer (score 2):

To use similar_text, you will need to get cross join the two tables, get an array of the outcome and use the similar_text function in the result array.
If you do that, you could save the result in a third auxiliar table.

However, you could use MySQL's native function `SOUNDEX()`, will which work, or [create a Levehnstein function](http://kristiannissen.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/mysql-levenshtein/).