# PHP check for double posting on the site

Tags: php

I want to run a check when a user submits a form that will compare the new post to old once to avoid double (or more) postings of the same content.

I thought of something like

```
if(strtolower($string1) == strtolower($string2))
{
//do this
}
```

but not sure how that would work for checking an entire website full of posts with unique id's

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you worried about same exact content?  Or, do you need to fuzzy-match against existing content?

Comment: I guess second one, but ideally both options to avoid spam of posts that are essentially the same

Comment: It's impossible to help you further without knowing more about your site.  This isn't a PHP problem... it's a problem for how you store your data.  You essentially need to run a search against existing posts, and if a match scores above a certain threshold, block the user from posting it.  Look into Solr and similar.

Comment: i have a table for title, and content for each post stored in the database. every time a post is posted, a new row is created in that table. I want to know how to compare the rows to see if there is similar stuff in it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`similar_text`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) in PHP..

```
<?php 
$post1 = 'test1'; 
$post2 = 'test2'; 
similar_text($post1, $post2, $percent); 
if(round($percent)>90)
{
  echo "The two posts are 90% similar.. sorry try again. No spamming !";
}
```

Comment: How do I check it with a more dynamic approach? I have a lot of posts and it will keep growing with users postings

Comment: So from the `comments` I see you have title and content.. So you can make use of `levenshtein()` on MySQL. See this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9871175/1003917)

Comment: @Gadgetster Definitely do this on the data side.  Don't do this in PHP or you will have to fetch everything your database every time someone makes a post.

Comment: what do you mean do this on data side? How do I do that? I was going to just try the levenshtein() thing but I see that it isn't really good for heavier loads of posts